# Can a method annotated with @InitBinder be marked as static?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) and several examples of `@InitBinder` online, I never see these methods marked as `static`.  My IDE is claiming they can be marked as `static`, I don't see any errors while doing so, and conceptually I would think you can mark it this way.

Are there any downsides to doing so?  I understand that the method must not return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside Spring Web that handles `@InitBinder` annotation does not make any 
assumptions or requirements whether it is static or not.

The difference between static and non-static `@InitBinder` method boils down to standard Java semantics of static and non-static methods, meaning the access to non-static variables and an ability to override the method.

If you do not need the instance variables or methods, you can safely make `@InitBinder` method static, and also private.

Regardless of whether the `@InitBinder` method static or not, it **can be called multiple times per request**, like at least once for each `@PathVariable`, `@RequestParam`, `@RequestHeader` or `@CookieValue` parameter of the request processing method. You can check the target bound to the `WebDataBinder` object using `WebDataBinder#getObjectName()` and customize the binder configuration based on that information.